# .htaccess добавление в исключение поддомен

Tags: .htaccess

Пытаюсь отправить POST запрос с одного поддомена на другой но появляется ошибка:

```
Failed to load https://sub2.site.com/query.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://sub1.site.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Вот .htaccess поддомена на которого идёт запрос.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/query.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Пытался добавить исключения, но устранить ошибку никак не удается.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно добавить в исключение поддомены сайта и разрешить отправлять им заголовки.

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.site\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</ifmodule>
```